# Library Retarget File and Low Level I/O Routines in Keil RealView uvision MDK IDE

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, keil

I just started to program in Keil uvision IDE. I am reading the official Keil documents about [Library Target Files](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/gsac_retargetcortex.htm) and [Low Level I/O Routines](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/gsac/gsac_lowlevelroutinescortex.htm). Seemingly I need to implement both of these functions for my devices. However, I have no idea how to start. Can anybody point me to the right place?

I am probably looking for a lazy excuse, but I imagine there should be generic implemented files for popular devices and developers shouldn't have to write them again? If I am right, where can I find those files? I am using Freescale MKL05Z32VFM4, an ARM Cortex M0+ device, if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to implement those if you are going to be calling low level IO routines.

Often, providing an implementation of `putc` is all that is required (allowing debug by `printf`) and the rest of the low-level infrastructure is not needed for a typical deeply embedded system such as that processor is often used for.

Implementing `putc` is (at its simplest) just a matter of copying a character to the appropriate register in the serial port peripheral.  More complex solutions can include interrupt-driven FIFO based transmission.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly, I am looking for the implementation of printf. are there more details about how to implement that? Or can you point me to a place you can help me start?

Comment: Martin, another question: if I need to read from the Flash memory chip, is that also a part of low-level IO routines?

Comment: You don't have to implement `printf` - the c library already has that.  all you need to provide is the lowest level "send a character out" function `putc`.

Comment: Regarding flash - really, if you have further questions, about unrelated items, you should ask them as a new question (stackoverflow doesn't operate like a discussion board)